# data-content is showing raw html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

`data-content` is showing raw html as plain text in output while i am using `data-content = ""`, I have added `data-html="true"`

```
<div data-html="true" data-content="text 1 <br /> text 3"  class="image">
```

Getting output in browser - `text 1 <br /> text 3`
Link to demo - http://new.praavahealth.com/webupcomingevent (hover on images)

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide a fiddle? here's a working one http://jsfiddle.net/qy9Az/2760/

Comment: Unfortunately the pseudo before/after element does not support insertion of HTML, only plain text. If you want to keep the HTML in the attribute and have it output to the page, you will need an alternative solution (i.e. JavaScript).

Comment: Can you please suggest me the javascript? thanks